# EF Code First Migrations - not detecting changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

Preword: In my database table i have two fields: (string)`(FK)UserPayoffData_UserName` and (int)`UserPayoffDataUserName`. I made a mistake, and in reality, i would like it to be only single property, (string)`(FK)UserPayoffData_UserName`, but called (string)`(FK)UserPayoffDataUserName`, and my second field ((int)`UserPayoffDataUserName`) would be gone.

now, in my model, i had this invalid property:

`public int UserPayoffDataUserName { get; set; }`

So I changed it to a string (now if i would drop my database and recreated it, it would be a foreign key):

`public string UserPayoffDataUserName { get; set; }`

Now I did `Add-migration mymigration`, and what i would expect is, that migrations would somehow rename above foreign key with properly named one. But it doesn't do anything. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Doesn't it create a migration of some sort?  Is it empty?  Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this clearly, you need to delete `mymigration` or any other old migrations you have from you project. They should be in your `Migration folder`. If you need your migrations, you are going to have to create new ones. Then change up your classes as you wish, like property naming and all your property mapping. Then build your solution, and run `Update-Database -Force`.

Remember, since you are working with `EF Code First`, you can delete you database, from your `Server Explorer` and your `App_Data` folder (Don't miss this, deleting from server explorer means nothing if you don't do it here) and its no big deal, as it can be created in an instant with `` `Update-Database -Verbose ``

Answer (score 0):

By doing the `Add-Migration mymigration` you are just creating your scaffolded code file that will be used when you execute the migration.

So your database won't change automatically. You have to initiate it!

By using the `update-database -TargetMigration mymigration`, this will execute all the change you made and saved to the mymigration file